# Почему выдается ошибка "'DesktopSize' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element."?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Почему выдается ошибка "'DesktopSize' cannot be used as a JSX component.   Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element."? По разному пытался, не исчезает.

```
interface ResponsiveProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | null
}

export const DesktopSize = ({ children }: ResponsiveProps) => {
  const isNotMobile = true
  return isNotMobile ? children : null

}

const TestComponent = () => {
  return <div>
    <DesktopSize>
      <div>
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
    </DesktopSize>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `React.ReactNode` укажите `JSX.Element`.